# Create an array containing a mix of method groups

Tags: c#, delegates

So I have a function that runs a set of steps in order, logging each one, killing the whole group if something fails and so on. If I have sync tasks, then I can do:

```
void A() => Console.WriteLine("A");
void B() => Console.WriteLine("B");
void C() => Console.WriteLine("C");

var functions = new Action[] { A, B, C };
```

and that works. For async - I can do:

```
Task A() => Task.Delay(1);
Task B() => Task.Delay(2);
Task C() => Task.Delay(3);

var functions = new Func<Task>[] { A, B, C };
```

and that also works - but I can find NO way of doing

```
Task A() => Task.Delay(1);
void B() => Console.Writeline("B");

var functions = new ??????[] { A, B };
```

I tried creating a class called `Step` with static implicit operators from `Action` and from `Func<Task>` - which I thought should have worked... but it didn't. :(

Comment: All of your code doesn't work. Can you post real code please?

Comment: None of your "asynchronous" methods are in fact asynchronous.  They're all entirely synchronous.

Comment: Your two choices are `var tasks = new Func<Task>[] { A, () => Task.Run(() => B()) };` or `var tasks = new Delegate[] { A, B };`.

Comment: the whole idea is to end up with the simple list with no symbols in it - so the first one is out - and I tried the second one and it just didn't work - can't convert method group to delegate :(

Comment: Let's say that you create this array. How do you intend to use it? Are you planning to invoke all the delegates in a loop, ignoring the return value of the delegates that have one?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all the functions in the array will have zero parameters, and they will defer only at their return type?

Comment: they are all "actions" - ie they have no parameters and no return values - they only differ as to whether they are sync or async

Comment: If none of the methods have a return value and they're all void, then why do your examples include methods with a return value that cause your methods to not be the same signature in the first place?  If all of your methods are actions and you have no return values, then all of your methods are of the same signature and there is no question.

Comment: Task is not a method with a return value